# I tried and saw that the notification should come to me at the specified time?

Tags: android, notifications

I tried and saw that the notice should come to me at the specified time and it did not come to me
**.setContentTitle(title.get("Title of notification"))
.setContentText(subText.get("Sub text of notification"))**
title subtext error

Notice should come only to me at the specified time I should be notified only at the time I place it

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NotificationCheckPoint();
    }
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void NotificationCheckPoint() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 53);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent MyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BroadastNotification.class);
        PendingIntent MyPendIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100,
                MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager MyAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        MyAlarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, MyPendIntent);


    }
```

This BroadcastNotication

```
public class BroadcastNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sendNotification(context);
    }

    private void sendNotification(Context context) {


        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "101";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

            //Configure Notification Channel
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Game Notifications");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{200});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle(title.get("Title of notification"))
                .setContentText(String.substring("Sub text of notification"))

                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);


        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the full code for BroadastNotification.java instead of uploading a screenshot. It will make it far easier to pinpoint any issues in your code.

Comment: i will post coding sir

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement is to basically show a notification every day at a fixed time using the `AlarmManager`.
This is how I implemented this in my earlier project

BroacastReceiver.java :-

```
public class BroadcastNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private int notificationID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (context != null && intent != null) {
            showNotification(context);
        }
            
    }

    private Notification createNotification(@NonNull Context context) {
        
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "101";

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)

                .setContentTitle(SharedPreferenceHelper.getTitle(context))
                .setContentText(SharedPreferenceHelper.getContent(context))

                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(localNotification.content));
                

        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {

        Notification notification = createNotification(context, localNotification)

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, 
                "Notification", 
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }


        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);

        notificationID++;
}
```

NotificationScheduler.java

```
public class NotificationScheduler {
    @Nullable
    public static String scheduleRepeatingNotification(@NonNull Activity activity) {

        setNotificationData(activity, "Title of notification", "Sub text of notification")

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 53);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        PendingIntent MyPendIntent = makePendingIntent(activity);

        AlarmManager MyAlarm = (AlarmManager) activity.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        MyAlarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, MyPendIntent);
    }

    public static PendingIntent makePendingIntent(Activity activity) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, BroadastNotification.class);

        // If you have multiple notifications, you'll have to update the requestCode accordingly. its 100 in this case.
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 100,
            myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

SharedPreferenceHelper.java :-

```
public class SharedPreferenceHelper {
    @Nullable
    public static String getNotificationTitle(@NonNull Context context) {

        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("NotificationSharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sp.getString("notification-title", null);
    }

    @Nullable
    public static String getNotificationContent(@NonNull Context context) {

        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("NotificationSharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sp.getString("notification-content", null);
    }

    public void setNotificationData(@NonNull Context context, String title, String content) {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("NotificationSharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        sp.edit().putString("notification-title", title).apply();
        sp.edit().putString("notification-content", content).apply();
    }
}
```

**Note:-**
This is an incomplete solution and requires a lot of additional code to handle all the scenarios.
For one, when the device reboots the AlarmManager is cleared, so you will have to handle the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`, `ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED`, `ACTION_REBOOT` and `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` events in this broadcast receiver.

Or follow this link to implement LocalNotifications using `WorkManager` -> https://martian.ventures/mantra/insights/schedule-local-notifications-on-android/

*Please correct any syntax error if found.*